# Error: Parse error Expecting 'EOF', '}', ':', ',', ']'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, parsing, ruby-on-rails-4

Following the Getting Started with Rails tutorial, and upon submitting the form I'm getting this error: https://cloudup.com/cdZ-xQkfnmm. I've got everything the same as the tutorial except that I've changed 'article' to 'user'.

```
<%= form_for :user, url: users_path do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :text %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :text %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>


class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def new
    end

    def create
        render plain: params[:user].inspect
    end
end
```

I'm not sure what other information I can give right now.

Comment: Your hash isn't a valid JSON. Try instead... `render plain: params[:user].to_json`

Comment: That works to get it into json, but when then it's giving me an error in the next step of creating a new user.

Comment: So what this has boiled down to is that I'm getting very odd results when creating tables inside of a custom migration instead of using the command line. I tried to work backwards thinking that this was actually the problem but I think it's deeper than that.

Comment: @ELepolt Did you figure it out ? Why was the error? I am getting the same error (And yes, I can change it to "to_json" but I want to understand why is the error)

Answer (score 2):

I had faced similar issue but later figured it out that my browser's JSONView extension did not recognise it as a valid json and hence it was throwing error. By turning it off, things started to work fine :)

Answer (score 1):

This also works:

```
render json: params[:user]
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this line in your controller:

```
render plain: params[:article].to_json
```

I got this response:

```
{
title: "title test",
text: "test of the text"
}
```